# WP theme jquery

Tags: wordpress

How do you add custom javascript/jquery to WordPress theme? I tried the steps on this site http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script with no luck.

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sample', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sample.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.

Comment: `function theme_scripts() { 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'sample', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sample.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
 } 

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');`

Comment: Where did you put the code ? Is that for your `front end` ?

Comment: It's in `functions.php` inside the theme's folder

Comment: Where should I put my js file?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), you need to define your jQuery through `wp_enqueue_script`.

So for theme it would be something like this :

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fwds_scripts');

    function fwds_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script('slidesjs_core', get_template_directory_uri('js/jquery.slides.min.js', __FILE__), array("jquery"));
        wp_enqueue_script('slidesjs_core');


        wp_register_script('slidesjs_init', get_template_directory_uri('js/slidesjs.initialize.js', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('slidesjs_init');

    }
```

Here what I have defined `wp_enqueue_script` as jQuery. You can skip this step also.

Second step, I have register my jQuery/JavaScript.In that `slidejs_core` is the **handle** which is unique to define that script.Second is **URL**. You need to first write `get_template_directory_uri`(which is URL to your theme) and them other path where you haev store your **JS**. I have made **JS** folder and in that folder I have saved my JS file .So my path is `js/jquery.slides.min.js`. Then I have defined **Array**, which is helpful to load that particular script before our script.This array is **optional**.

After you need to add `wp_enqueue_script` through your **handles** which we defined in `wp_register_script`.

Comment: You only need to *register* jQuery, as the following enqueue will automatically enqueue all needed dependencies (e.g. `slidesjs_core` will auto-enqueue `jquery` in your example if `jquery` is registered somewhere). Enqueuing on each and every page is not necessary.

Comment: Yes You are right. But by doing this way, it will not cause any problem.

Comment: True, just pointing out for the folks that want to optimize some more. :)

Comment: no luck

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');

   function custom_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script('custom',       get_template_directory_uri('js/sample.js', __FILE__),     array("jquery"));
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');
}`

Comment: Have you checked through debugging ? check that either JS is there or not ? Because above code is **TESTED**.

Comment: Try this `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sample.js' );`